# How to Merge Specific Rows from Specific Columns in Python

Tags: python, merge, split

If there's an easier way to do this, please let me know. I read a .txt file into Python, and the delimiting isn't consistent. I tried using 't' tab delimiter spacing among other spacing techniques, but it appears there are more spaces between columns than others. As such, it isn't that simple.

I loaded the data with

`df = pd.read_table(data.txt, header = None)`

This gave me a single string column, which I then used string split to divide the data into the 8 columns I need. Dataframe before splitting:

`df = df['col1'].str.split(expand = True)`

However, the problem is the first column (Name) of my data frame consists of strings. Some of these strings have two or three individual words, so when I use string split, each piece of the string is being put into its own column. I now need to merge select rows of columns 1, 2, and sometimes 3 into the same cell.

Current data structure:

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f
0   Bantam  1601    6   3   0   2
1   Malacca Strait  1606    14  11  0
2   Ilha    das Naus    1606    6   9
3   Pulo    Butum   1606    7   9   0
4   Surrat  1615    6   0   4   1.5
```

As can be seen from the dataframe above, the string splint ended up with name being put into more than one column, where name1 denotes the first part of the string, name 2 denotes the second part, and name 3 denotes the third part.

What I want the dataframe to look like:

```
        a            b      c   d   e   f
0   Bantam          1601    6   3   0   2
1   Malacca Strait  1606    14  11  0
2   Ilha das Naus   1606    6   9
3   Pulo Butum      1606    7   9   0
4   Surrat          1615    6   0   4   1.5
```

Is there a way to merge these cells such that my name column has all parts of the name (name1, and name2 and name3 if necessary)?

I looked into concatenation and merging, but I couldn't figure out how to do it on specific cells. I'm still learning python. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please share a sample of your dataframe before splitting it.

Comment: @MayankPorwal just added!

Comment: Please also update the expected output based on the just added df. Also, make sure to edit column names. Currently, you are splitting on `col1`, which does not exist in your main `df`.

Comment: I changed the names for anonymity. I updated everything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `data.txt` file contains more than 2 white spaces between the columns. If so, you could use the `sep` parameter with a regular expression as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv('data/data.txt', sep='\s{2,}', header=None, engine="python")
    print(df)
```

Result:

```
                0     1   2   3  4      5  6  7
0          Bantam  1601   6   3  0  2.000  0  0
1  Malacca Strait  1606  14  11  0  1.273  0  0
2   Ilha das Naus  1606   6   9  0  0.667  0 -1
3      Pulo Butum  1606   7   9  0  0.778  0  1
4          Surrat  1615   6   0  4  1.500  0  0
5   Ilha das Naus  1615   3   5  0  0.600  0 -1
6            Jask  1620   4   0  4  1.000  0  0
```